# Rank correlations with very coarse reference

Tags: ordinal-data, rating

I have some data about 50 hotels (for this example).
They are rated 1-5 stars -- the ground truth.

Then I have a number of different estimators which use some features to output a score.
For example one estimator might be say "[average_room_cost] + 100*([number of staff]/[number_of_rooms])" which outputs a score between 50 and 10000.
Another might be "[Average Yelp Review]*[average_room_cost]"

All my other estimators are similar, all outputting roughly scores between 50 and 10000 (give or take an order of magnitude.).

I want to work out which estimator is best.

To do this I am using a rank correlation.
Currently I am using Kendall's rank correlation, as I understand it handles ties better than Spearman's.
There are a lot of ties in the ground truth ranks -- there are only 5 ranks and there are 50 hotels.
but ties are very rare between scores given by 1 estimator.

Is this the best way to assess it?
Or are there special rating correlations?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to predict an outcome which is an ordered categorical variable you could investigate ordinal regression. In this case proportional odds would seem to fit since you have an essentially continuous variable of hotel quality which you have observed in a coarsened form. You could then compare models using something like AIC.